# how can add an input field to File upload windows(Browse button) in C#

Tags: c#, dialog

How can add an input field to Open File dialog box (Browse button) in C# and how can get the selected path in to variable???[Open File dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsPzI.jpg)

After "File Name" input field i want to add another input field.How can add it?and i want to retrieve the folder path in to a variable .Is it possible

Comment: There is no simple way to modify that dialog.

Comment: Is there any other way to create custom open file dialog box in c# ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to extend the FileOpenDialog.

Please see the link to codeplex: https://www.codeproject.com/kb/dialog/customizefiledialog.aspx

This includes a demo on how to extend the file open dialog.

Regarding getting the folder path. This can be accomplished by using the System.Windows.File  GetDirectory properties on the result from the fileopendialog file path.

Ex: var ofd = new ...;

var folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName);